# Drag and Drop stops working after serialization and deserialization in Java

Tags: java, serialization, drag-and-drop, deserialization

I am developing an Java application. The frame structure of the application is as follows.
First i have JFrame which contains a panel. in the panel i have a number of JLists and between the Jlists i have implemented the Drag and Drop feature. 
Now each time before closing application i want to save the contents of the UI. for which i am using serialization and deserialization and i have successfully implemented it. After the deserialization all the things are working as expected except drag and drop. I am not getting any errors but the drag and drop handler is not established for the Jlists. I tried to put some print statements in the drag and drop handler and was getting no result. Can any one tell me what can be a possible reason for that ?

following is the definition of the DnDhandler that i have added to each Jlist Component

```
$private ListTransferHandler dndHandler = new ListTransferHandler();
```

and my ListTranferHandler class something like

```
$public class ListTransferHandler extends TransferHandler implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = -3484014856820532284L;
//followed by all methods
    // canImport
    // createtranferable
    // getSourceActions
    // importData
    //exportDone
}
```

Comment: At a guess, I'd first look for places in your code where there's an == rather than a .equals(). You would do yourself a favour making the smallest piece of compilable, standalone code that you can which reproduces the bug. People could help you better with that information.

Comment: Although i have resolved the problem by serializing the contents and avoiding serializing UI components still i will post a sample code which which can make problem clear so that actual problem can be identified

Answer (score 0):

In general, when working with swing, although the various components *are* Serializable, it's best *not* to serialize them directly.  if you want to persist the data, serialize the data, not the swing elements themselves.